# showing attributes in table (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

How can I write an SQL query to show all the attributes in the table which are not NULL?

Answer (score 4):

You can list all columns in a table which are defined as NOT NULL with a query like this:

```
select column_name
from USER_TAB_COLUMNS
where table_name = 'MYTABLE'
and nullable = 'N';
```

(If the table is not owned by the logged-in user, you can query ALL_TAB_COLUMNS instead.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because some records will have some attribute null, and some other records will have this attribute not null.

If an attribute is always null, just drop the column.

Comment: I want to say that for PK='...' show all attributes that are not null,Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the describe command

```
DESC TABLENAME;
```

Comment: If this post answers the question, provide additional text to explain how. You may also want to add surrounding code to help others who have similar questions